# Parsing a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file that looks similar to the following:

```
Book
Key: Norris2013
Author: Elizabeth Norris
Title: Unbreakable
Publisher: Harper Collins Publishers
Date: 2013
Book
Key: Rowling1997
Author: J.K. Rowling
Title: Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
Publisher: Bloomsbury Publishing
Date: 1997
Book
Key: Dickens1894
Author: Charles Dickens
Title: A tale of two cities
Publisher: Dodd, Mead
```

EDIT: I am entering data into the dictionary like so:

```
newDict = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split()
        newDict[splitLine[0]] = " ".join(splitLine[1:])
print (newDict)
```

Why is it only printing out the last entry to the dictionary?

Comment: It is very simple, But you need to show some work before we do anythin

Comment: Read the lines one by one. If the line is `Book`, it starts a new book, otherwise the line has a key-value field, with these items separated by `: `. These should be read to a dictionary, or an instance of a class. Now translate this to Python and you're done.

Comment: added code that I am using. But cannot figure out why it is only printing the last entry.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the dictionary again and again since you're reusing the same keys multiple times. You probably want to create a list of dictionaries:

```
books = []    # Start with an empty list
book = {}     # and an empty dictionary for the current book
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == "Book":  # Are we at the start of a new book? Then...
            if book:                # Add the current book (if there is one) to list
                books.append(book)
                book = {}           # Start a new book
        else:
            splitLine = line.strip().split()
            book[splitLine[0]] = " ".join(splitLine[1:])
if book:                            # Add final book to list
    books.append(book)
print (books)
```